# The process of creating a complete character, including animation

Tags: modeling, texturing, workflow

I have a simple low poly 3d character.

1. I would like to use some method to add more polygons to the head area to create more detail to the head area (then sculpting modeling). Which network densification method should ideally be used, or why?
2. When I implement point 1. What is the next procedure? Unwrap, texture painting and rigging?

Thanks for any clarifications or tips

Comment: This is not really a tutorial site. You can add and then apply a subdivision surface modifier to increase the number of vertices, but if your character is a single object that will affect the whole model. As far as the rest of your question is concerned you should watch some basic modelling UV unwrapping and texture painting tutorials and the same with rigging. There are hundreds online including many YT videos.

Comment: Are the new details supposed to be part of the topology of the object or do you plan to bake them to the low-poly? In that case duplicate your object, apply a Subdivision Surface modifier to the copy and sculpt on it. But you don't give enough details here

Comment: Hi, I have a human figure, about 40,000 polygons. I would like to apply some modifier to the head, such as subdivision, which will thicken me in that area. I will use sculpting then to add more details on head. I will have a finished model. Subsequently, I would complete the unwrap, textures and add bones, animation to the character. Just a need a short answer to the question of whether and possibly what modifier I can add to the head. In the 3ds max its common workflow, I can thicken selected polygons and sculpt. Is this possible in a blender or do I have to separate the head from the body?